# How to get correct file size only on the completion of a detected file change, not at the beginning?

Tags: c++, file, stat, libuv

I'm using libuv's [uv_fs_event_t](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/fs_event.html) to monitor file changes. And once a change is detected, I open the file in the callback `uv_fs_event_cb`.

However, my program requires to also get the full file size when opening the file, so I would know how much memory is to be allocated based on the file size. I found that no matter I use libuv's `uv_fs_fstat` or POSIX's `stat/stat64`, or `fseek+ftell` I never get the correct file size immediately. It's because when my program is opening the file, the file is still being updated.

My program runs in a tight single thread with callbacks so delay/sleep isn't the best option here (and no guaranteed correctness either).

Is there any way to handle this with or without leveraging libuv, so that I can, say hold off opening and reading the file, until the write to the file has completed? In other words, instead of immediately detects the start of a change of a file event, can I in some way detects a **completion** of a file change?

Comment: Have you looked at `sync()` and `fsync()` to ensure all filesystem changes are flushed before you attempt to determine the size?

Comment: I don't think libuv can tell you when changes are done. If you're on Linux, you can use inotify, which can be configured to notify when a file is closed. But then you have to write your own event handler loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to have the writer create an intermediate file, and finish I/O by renaming it to the target file. e.g. this is what happens in most browsers, the file has an "downloading.tmp" name until download is complete to discourage you from opening it.

Another approach is to write/touch a "finished" file after writing the main target file, and wait to see that file before the reader starts his job.

Last option I can see, if the file format can be altered slightly, have the writer print the file size as first bytes of the file, then the reader can preallocate correctly even if the file is not fully written, and then it will insist on reading all the data.

Overall I'm suggesting instead of a *completion event*, make the writer produce any event that can be monitored after it has completed it's task, and have the reader wait/synchronize on that event.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try the combination of writing temporary file and move, plus adding a preamble header on file size.